# Reversed (or previously applied) patch detected! Assume -R? [n]

Tags: linux, diff, patch

Friends,
I try to create a patch file and then apply the patch. ./uboot-imx/common/cli_readline.c is original, and ./dw/cli_readline.c is the modified.

diff -u ./uboot-imx/common/cli_readline.c ./dw/cli_readline.c >diff.patch

cat diff.patch

```
--- ./uboot-imx/common/cli_readline.c   2019-02-26 11:35:25.999790801 -0700
+++ ./dw/cli_readline.c 2019-02-27 09:41:33.943772020 -0700
@@ -14,6 +14,8 @@
 #include <cli.h>
 #include <watchdog.h>

+#define UART_ON 1 //dw_debug: comment it to disable UART.
+
 DECLARE_GLOBAL_DATA_PTR;
 cat diff.patch
--- ./uboot-imx/common/cli_readline.c   2019-02-26 11:35:25.999790801 -0700
+++ ./dw/cli_readline.c 2019-02-27 09:41:33.943772020 -0700
@@ -14,6 +14,8 @@
 #include <cli.h>
 #include <watchdog.h>

+#define UART_ON 1 //dw_debug: comment it to disable UART.
+
 DECLARE_GLOBAL_DATA_PTR;
```

/* apply patch */

patch -p0< diff.patch

**patching file ./dw/cli_readline.c**

**Reversed (or previously applied) patch detected!  Assume -R? [n]**

2 questions:

1. I was expect apply patch to  ./uboot-imx/common/cli_readline.c but instead, it try to apply patch to ./dw/cli_readline.c
2. ./dw/cli_readline.c never patched. why it says patch detected?

please give me advance.

thanks

Answer (score 3):

spend hours figured out the issue.
I (maybe most of guys) thought patch take the "---dir/org_file" in patch file as the file to apply patch. indeed, that is wrong. in my case above, it take the second file
start with "+++" as file to apply patch.

rm ./dw/cli_readline.c
then apply patch. issue is gone